# Detect cancel user action when programmatically install apk

Tags: android

my question is:
How to detect when user cancel install apk ?
My code to install is:

```java
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // detect if user install apk
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    filter.addDataScheme("package");

    context.startActivity(intent);
```

So i can detect when user is installed/updated package but can't detect when user cancel install apk activity. How to solve this ?

Comment: In the future, it may be helpful to leave a more complete example.  And also, an explanation of why this is being done in code and not in the manifest may be beneficial as well.